# How to access another app model in django?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I have two apps main and table 
in my main I have a model UserSelect and in table is a model Bowler
I need to do this

```
from main.models import UserSelect, User

class Bowlers(models.Model):
 users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='UserSelect')
```

but it gives error that 
"Field specifies a many-to-many relation through model 'UserSelect', which has not been installed"
so how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have lazy references to models from any app by referencing it with a string

```
class Bowlers(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField('main.User', through='main.UserSelect')
```

But the specific issue you are having is that you should pass the `UserSelect` class as the through argument not as a string

```
class Bowlers(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through=UserSelect)
```